# Boolean operation initiation in a Matrix application

Tags: logic

Given a function taking input matrix $A$ and $B$. The function only returns True if $A$ and $B$ are both vectors (either coulomb or row vector.) Is the following right?

---

if (numRow(A)!=1 and numCoulomb(AB)!=1) or (numRow(B)!=1 and numCoulomb(B)!=1):
return False

else: return True.

---

I felt the above somewhat non-intuitive, do the above logic seems intuitive to you? Or you need to use certain methods to figure them out or take some time doing trial-error to figure it out. Very confused.... Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the $AB$ in your first clause is meant to be $A$, this is correct and a natural way to express this. You're just saying "if $A$ is not a vector and $B$ is not a vector" and expanding "not a vector" into "has neither one row nor one column." Regarding the methodology, what I just did is all I ever do: express the statement in natural language and break it into pieces small enough to translate into formal logic. If this isn't easy for you, then of course trial and error usually works for small Boolean problems.

Comment: Thank you. I just have troubles doing this even in natural language... Maybe its because English is not my first language, or maybe it is because of my OCD.... Thank you:-)